How can I get the program to print each line on a new paragraph?
I wrote this shopping program myself and I'm trying to get it to print to the shell and to the text file with each shopping list item on a new line. Please can you help me with this?
#By Simeon Beckford-Tongs BSc MSc Copyright © 2024. All rights reserved. By Simeon Beckford-Tongs BSc MSc Copyright © 2024. All rights reserved. 

items = input('What is the first item on your shopping list:\n')
items += input('What is the second item on your shopping list:\n')
items += input('What is the third item on your shopping list:\n')
items += input('What is the fourth item on your shopping list:\n')
items += input('What is the fith item on your shopping list:\n')
items += input('What is the sixth item on your shopping list:\n')
items += input('What is the seventh item on your shopping list:\n')
items += input('What is the eighth item on your shopping list:\n')
items += input('What is the ninth item on your shopping list:\n')
items += input('What is the tenth item on your shopping list:\n')

shopping_list = 'shopping list:' 


file = open('shopping_list.txt', 'w')

file.write (items) 

file.close()

file = open('shopping_list.txt', 'r')

for line in file: 
    print( line, end = '\n')
file.close()


I tried adding a \n character(s) to lines 3-12 and line 26.

Linux/MacOS or Windows?  Line endings for windows is \n\r and \n for Unix-like

So, you are appending each item to the items variable, but you're not adding any newline characters (\n) between them, which results in them being concatenated together into one long string.
items = ""
items += input('What is the first item on your shopping list:\n') + '\n'
items += input('What is the second item on your shopping list:\n') + '\n'
items += input('What is the third item on your shopping list:\n') + '\n'
items += input('What is the fourth item on your shopping list:\n') + '\n'
items += input('What is the fifth item on your shopping list:\n') + '\n'
items += input('What is the sixth item on your shopping list:\n') + '\n'
items += input('What is the seventh item on your shopping list:\n') + '\n'
items += input('What is the eighth item on your shopping list:\n') + '\n'
items += input('What is the ninth item on your shopping list:\n') + '\n'
items += input('What is the tenth item on your shopping list:\n') + '\n'

shopping_list = 'shopping list:'

file = open('shopping_list.txt', 'w')

file.write(items)

file.close()

file = open('shopping_list.txt', 'r')

for line in file:
    print(line, end='\n')

file.close()

This should to do what you asked for.

Thank you so much! I really appreciate your consultation.

input doesn't return the newline that the user types to end the input, so you're concatenating each item into a single string items end-to-end. You can make items a list instead of a string and then use "\n".join(items) or the like, or you can append "\n" to items after you add each item.

There is no problems found in the code. It works fime.
Maybe it can further be simplified.
#Since all the questions are same except order differs, the orders alone can be declared as a list
orders =['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh', 'eighth', 'ninth','tenth' ]


#to avoid opening and closing of file eachtime, A method with open is available
with open ('shopping_list.txt', 'w') as file:

    # Instead of writing 10 times, a forloop is created. The arder is called by orders[i]
    for i in range(10):
        item = input(f'What is the {orders[i]} item on your shopping list:\n')
        file.write(f'{item}\n')

with open ('shopping_list.txt', 'r') as file:
    line_list = file.readlines()
for line in line_list:
    print(line, end ='\n')  

